# Is there build-in way to detect user agent inside a template?

Tags: drupal, http-headers, twig, user-agent

Is there build-in Twig way to detect user agent and user IP if website is powered by Drupal 8.x ?

Something like `app.request.headers.get('User-Agent')`

I mean without adding custom Twig function on PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Browser detect module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/browser_detect